# remove html from the titles of Post and Page Columns of wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, trim, dashboard

I would like to remove HTML from the  titles of Post and Page Columns of wordpress dashboard as in the image attached.
Normally wordpress wont have html tags in the title.But as part of a plugin creation i need to remove these htmls tags .I am trying to create a Tynimce editor to the title fields

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot wordpress dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that HTML is right in your title-field.

Why is it there? It´s absolutely not the right place for markup.

Comment: its for adding css to the title.For creating a plugin of that purpose

Comment: The theme should output the title as a class, if necessary. You should not add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace your Title Column with the Existing one //
function replace_title_column($columns) {

    $new = array();

    foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
        if ($key=='title') 
        $new['new-title'] = __(Title); // Our New column Name
        $new[$key] = $title;
    }

    unset($new['title']); 
    return $new;
}

// Replace the title with your custom title
function replace_title_products($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'new-title') {
        $cont = get_the_title();
    $cont = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $cont);
    $cont = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $cont);
    $cont = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $cont); ?>
    <a class="row-title" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-admin/post.php?post=<?php echo $post_ID; ?>&action=edit"><?php echo strip_tags($cont); ?></a>
    <?php
    }
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'replace_title_column');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'replace_title_products', 10, 2);
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'replace_title_column');
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'replace_title_products', 10, 2);
```